# Copy AWS S3 file to AWS Aurora Postgres directly

Tags: postgresql-9.6, amazon-aurora

I am trying to insert few CSV file data into Aurora Postgres DB. 
Tried out various COPY commands but none of them work. Is it not achievable ? 
Is there a way in which I can do this without downloading the file or using the datapipelines ?